# Getting an Instance from 'unsafeAddressOf'

Tags: swift2

I encode an `Int64` (on the graphics card)  with  `unsafeAddressOf` of some instances (that are properly stored in and retained by some array).

I then would like to get back to my instances from my `Int64`. I manage to get an `UnsafePointer<MyClass>` correctly initialized from my `Int64`.

Then, I do:

```
let x = UnsafePointer<MyClass>.memory.
```

But using `x` crashes.

I understand it is unsafe and tricky considering ARC. But still, is there any way to achieve this in Swift, or is it helpless?

Thanks.

Comment: "I manage to get an UnsafePointer<MyClass> correctly initialized from my Int64." show us this part of code, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is extremely unsafe, as you yourself said, and there are probably safer approaches to solving whatever problem you are working on, but here is a complete example that does it:

```
func getPointer<T:AnyObject>(obj : T) -> Int64
{
    return unsafeBitCast(unsafeAddressOf(obj), Int64.self)
}

func recoverObject<T:AnyObject>(ptr : Int64) -> T
{
    return Unmanaged<T>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(bitPattern: Int(ptr))).takeUnretainedValue()
}

class C {
    var cID = 0
    func foo() {
        print("Instance of C, id = \(cID)")
    }
}

class D {
    var dID = 0
    func foo() {
        print("Instance of D, id = \(dID)")
    }
}


let c : C = C()
let d : D = D()

c.cID = 123;
d.dID = 321;

let cPtr : Int64 = getPointer(c)
let dPtr : Int64 = getPointer(d)

c.cID *= 10

let c1 : C = recoverObject(cPtr)
let d1 : D = recoverObject(dPtr)

c1.foo()
d1.foo()
```

The output is:

```
Instance of C, id = 1230
Instance of D, id = 321
```

Thanks to user3441734 for some helpful hints!  Note the use of generics.  The functions for getting a "pointer" and de-referencing it should work with any class (won't work with structs, though).

As far as safer ways of doing this, the answer would depend on the context of what you are doing.  Why can't the array of instances be accessed wherever you need the instances instead of obtaining them via Int64s?  If the array is actually maintained by (Objective-)C code in a 3rd party library, then there are additional problems that may arise due to memory alignment etc.  It may be possible to write C code that would return instances to Swift code in a safer way.

Please let me know about more details if the answer doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
class C {
    func foo() {
        print("C")
    }
}
var c = C()

let addr = unsafeAddressOf(c)
dump(addr)
/*
▿ UnsafePointer(0x7F86E942B230)
  - pointerValue: 140217415807536
*/

let pC = withUnsafePointer(&c) { (p) -> UnsafePointer<C> in
    return p
}

dump(pC)
/*
▿ UnsafePointer(0x10DE5B390)
  - pointerValue: 4528124816
*/

dump(pC.memory)
/*
- C #0
*/
let opaquePointer = COpaquePointer(addr)
let unmanagedC = Unmanaged<C>.fromOpaque(opaquePointer)
dump(unmanagedC)
/*
▿ Swift.Unmanaged<C>
- _value: C #0
*/

// I still dont have an idea how to use it ...
```

ha, i got it!

```
unmanagedC.takeUnretainedValue().foo() // prints    C !
```

Comment: That works ! You can see some extra details in this answer on apple dev forum : [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26655)